# while creating child DNS in windows server 2019 AD, parant dns is server 2008 prerequisites check failing

Tags: dns, active-directory, prerequisites, domaincontroller, windows-server-2019

I am getting error "Verification of prerequisites for Active Directory preparation failed . Unable to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot .
Exception : Unavailable Critical Extention .  Server extended error 8366. Server extended message : 000020AE:SvcErr:DSID-03210384,problem 5010(UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 8610

Adprep failed to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.

The schema is not upgraded

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.